# xsd attribute from type long

Tags: xml, xsd

i need to define some attribute in xsd-schema from type long between 0 and positive long
my code look like so ..

```
        <xsd:attribute name="spent-time">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
                <xsd:minInclusive value="0" />
                <xsd:maxInclusive value=" ...." />
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question. That is, put your answer in the proper place, not part of the question.

Comment: I have the question answered in the same day and therefore I could not answer my question in the same day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

i find it out

when i give it to minInclusive value="0" then take this attribute either 0 or something positive long value this looks like so

```
<xsd:attribute name="spent-time">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```